# Eclipse: Java heap space, How to fix it?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, fedora

i have an error at eclipse for a long time and i searched in stackoverflow for a solution, i found two diffirent suggestions but i try it without success.

First try, was to change the eclipse.ini file with the following changes,

Try allocating more heap space to eclipse. Go to eclipse.ini file in the eclipse directory and change heap space parameter.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
```

the second try is to start eclipse with a command like this :

```
eclipse -vmargs -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Sometimes it is working but after few hours the problem is back and sometimes i cannot solve this so i am waiting one day and the problem is away and it is coming again after some days. 
How can i fix it, because i cannot work on my project.

I am on Fedora 20.

Comment: Just add even more memory. For example, -Xmx1024m. 512m could be not enough for Eclipse these days.

Comment: 256M or 512M is too small to run a ide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The memory usage depends on what do you do in the Eclipse and which plugins you have installed, but according to my experience 512Mb is not enough for comfortable work. I use for Eclipse Luna 64bit (eclipse.ini):

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx1200m
```

With these settings I can have Eclipse opened for a week with hundreds of source files opened without having `OutOfMemoryError`.

Note that PermSize/MaxPermSize option is obsolete since Java-8 (it does not actually change anything).

Comment: My experience: 512mb is enough if you only do regular JavaSE work such as Swing/JavaFX or game development, but as soon as you start to do enterprisy stuff where a server will also be started and projects get a whole bunch of facets, builders and validators, better crank it up to 1gb.